# Why do Trills die if the symbiont is removed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In ST:DS9 S2E04 "Invasive Procedures" (and in other scenes where symbionts are implanted/removed) they imply that a joined Trill that has a symbiont removed **will, without doubt, die** within a fairly short time. Why is this? How is it that the symbionts can survive without being in a host, but the hosts are killed after symbionts are removed? The symbionts can live in those underground caves on Trill without being in a host.

> Jadzia is able to survive the fairly short period of time that Dax is removed, and Verad lives despite having the symbiont implanted *and* removed (they say because it was implanted for such a short amount of time). Doctor Bashir hints that she will live up to a day or so because she is young and healthy. Why isn't she able to recover from the surgery?

But there seems to be a lot of leeway in this. Is it ever shown exactly *why* it's so dangerous?

Comment: "***BASHIR**: The symbiont and the host are biologically interdependent. Ninety three hours after they've joined, neither can survive without the other.* (DS9: Dax). So the symbiont needs a series of new hosts after they've joined for the first time, too.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Jadzia was able to survive removal but it needed her own health and a genius doctor to do it.  This may go towards implying the Trills are exaggerating again and never had motivation to get good at removal treatments.  It's like losing a major organ no doubt but surely less dangerous than some bizarre DNA rewrite scifi diseases that get cured routinely.